# How to add number in filename while writing in a loop?

Tags: loops, lua

Acceleration is recorded in result.txt, but I want to record only 1 result in result.

I'd like to record next result in result_1.txt and then result_2.txt, result_3.txt

How can I record 1 result in 1 txt file?

This is my code.

```
local filename = "result.txt"

local file = io.open(filename, "a")

for i=1, 1000 do

    sim:stepForward()
    local p = ship.rb:getAcceleration():z()
    file:write(string.format("%d\n",p))

end

file:close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need different file handlers for each files to output.

For simplicity, assuming the file name begins with `result_1.txt`:

```
for i = 1, 1000 do
  local filename = "result_" + tostring(i) + ".txt"
  local file = io.open(filename, "a")
  -- write to file
  file:close()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To save each one to a different file you need to open and close each file individually. A function could be written to do this for you.

```
saveData = function ( data, path )
    local f = io.open(path, 'a')
    f:write(data)
    f:close()
end
```

Then you can call

```
saveData(string.format("%d\n",p), 'results_1.txt')
```

Now to get them all in an ascending order we simply use a loop and concatenate the number with the string.

```
for i = 1, 10, 1 do
     local path = 'results_'..i..'.txt'
     saveData(<insert data here>, path)
end
```

Alternatively, we can have all the data saved in a table.

```
data = { <insert data here>, ... }
```

Then save all the data in the table to their respective files.

```
for i, v in ipairs(data) do
     local path = 'results_'..i..'.txt'
     saveData(v, path)
end
```